# How to check what photo is currently presented on the screen by ImageView (in android)?

Tags: android, resources, imageview

A bit wierd problem:

Is it possible to get back id or/and a name of active resource in an ImageView? That's the code.

```
ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeForPhoto);
//here I choose random photo from drawable (photo 1 to photo 10)
//and then I show it on the screen as below
photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo1); //or photo2 or photo3 or...
```

In the other part of the code I would like to check which photo is atm presented in placeForPhoto. If it's R.drawable.photo1 or R.drawable.photo2 or...

So what I need is just smth like to have a possibility to achieve such a comparison:

```
if ([presented atm photo in ImagView photo] == R.drawable.photo1) 
{do something}
else if ([presented atm photo in ImagView photo] == R.drawable.photo2) 
{do smth different}
else {...}
```

I tried:
photo.getID() but it returns ID of placeForPhoto not for the resource inside;

photo.getResource() but it returns some other value different than id of photo

getResource().getIdentifier() but it gives id when you have the name and I don't have the name (or maybe it's possible to get the name from ImageView photo?)

getResources().getResourceName() but then I have to have id which I'm just looking for.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get back id or/and a name of active resource in an ImageView?

No, because an `ImageView` does not have to hold a resource. It could hold a bitmap obtained by other means (e.g., download from the Web).

> So what I need is just smth like to have a possibility to achieve such a comparison

Store the ID in a data member of the activity, or in the tag of the `ImageView` (i.e., `setTag()` and `getTag()`).

Comment: Thx. I was thinking about using tags, so if there is no resource id in imageview I go for them.